# Subview Not responding to the taps/touch;

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have created a TabbBar and used the following the get the other Viewcontroller in side a Subview like the follow.I am getiing the view loaded successfully ,but i am unable to interact with the Viewcontroller.view loaded inside the view.

Complete .m and .h file code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/jpLKBtnU)

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
[_InnerContentView removeFromSuperview];
_InnerContentView = nil;
_InnerContentView=[[UIView alloc]init];//UIView Inside the Main View;Used to add otherViews as sub Views
 vc=nil;//UIViewController;

switch (item.tag)
{
    case 10:

        vc=[[IndProjectViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"IndProjectViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Project";
        vc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,_InnerContentView.frame.size.width,_InnerContentView.frame.size.height-self.tabBar.frame.size.height);

       [_InnerContentView addSubview:vc.view];
       [self.view addSubview:_InnerContentView];
        break;

    case 11:
        vc=[[IndTasksViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"IndTasksViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Task";
        vc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,_InnerContentView.frame.size.width,_InnerContentView.frame.size.height-self.tabBar.frame.size.height);
        [_InnerContentView addSubview:vc.view];
        [self.view addSubview:_InnerContentView];
        break;
    case 12:
        vc=[[IndDocumentsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"IndDocumentsViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Documents";
        vc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0,_InnerContentView.frame.size.width,_InnerContentView.frame.size.height-self.tabBar.frame.size.height);

        [_InnerContentView addSubview:vc.view];
        [self.view addSubview:_InnerContentView];

        break;

}}
```

What's wrong with this.

Complete .m and .h file code can be seen [here](http://pastebin.com/jpLKBtnU)

Comment: What kind of interactions do you want to have with theses views? Which controller, the one with the tab bar, or the one whose view you're adding as a subview, do you want to respond to actions in the subview?

Comment: the subview inside the `InnerContentView`

Comment: as vc.view is load fine inside the InnerContentView but vc.view not receiving any touch event or any sort of interaction

Comment: i even enabled the userInteraction programmatically for the InnerContentView,still nothing happen

Comment: That doesn't really answer my questions. Which controller do you want to handle a touch for instance (vc or the controller with the tab bar)? What exactly are you trying to do in these views?

Comment: i want vc to receive the touch events as well .as these are having different form to take input from user

Comment: Then vc should be added as a child view controller of the controller with the tab bar. It's best practice to do that any time you're adding the view of one controller to another.

Comment: thanks for the telling me the best practice for adding the ViewController to other ViewController .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following in the UItabbar delgate method will fix the problem do check the following ,as it's a silly mistake that i encounter myself often .

```
    _InnerContentView.frame=CGRectMake(x, y,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-self.tabBar.frame.size.height-y);
```

after adding it will look like :

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{
 [_InnerContentView removeFromSuperview];
_InnerContentView = nil;
_InnerContentView=[[UIView alloc]init];
_InnerContentView.frame=CGRectMake(x, y,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-self.tabBar.frame.size.height-y);
  vc=nil;
switch (item.tag)
{
    case 10:
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Project";
        vc=[[IndProjectViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"IndProjectViewController" bundle:nil];
        vc.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, _InnerContentView.frame.size.width,_InnerContentView.frame.size.height-self.tabBar.frame.size.height);
        [_InnerContentView addSubview:vc.view];
        [self.view addSubview:_InnerContentView];
```